# Type of "SCNAudioSource *_steps[StepsSoundCount][AAPLFloorMaterialCount]"

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, scenekit

I found this interesting line of code in WWDC 15 Fox project,file APPLCharacter.m.Please just tell me the type,IDK much objective-c
 `SCNAudioSource *_steps[StepsSoundCount][AAPLFloorMaterialCount];`
Here is the enum
`typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, AAPLFloorMaterial) {
    AAPLFloorMaterialGrass,
    AAPLFloorMaterialRock,
    AAPLFloorMaterialWater,
    AAPLFloorMaterialInTheAir,
    AAPLFloorMaterialCount
};`and
`#define StepsSoundCount 10`

What type is _steps ?
How can this be translated into swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a static two-dimensional C array. That is an array of arrays of `SCNAudioSource` instances. The outer array is indexed by the "materials" and each sub-array contains a source for each step.

Comment: Thank you,now I know how to do it in swift.